# Unir uma pilha com uma lista

Tags: c

```
struct noPilha{
    float peso;
    int idMala;
    char cor[20];
    struct pessoa donoMala;
    struct noPilha* prox;
};

typedef struct noPilha Elem;

struct noLista{
    struct noPilha mala;
    struct noLista *ant;
    struct noLista *prox;
};

typedef struct noLista NoLista;

void insere_lista(Lista* l, Pilha *pi){

    NoLista* no;

        no = (NoLista*) malloc(sizeof(NoLista));

        no->mala.peso = pi->peso;
        no->prox = NULL;

        if((*l) == NULL){
            no->ant = NULL;
            *l = no;
        }else{
            NoLista* aux = *l;
            while(aux->prox != NULL){
                aux = aux->prox;
            }
            aux->prox = no;
            no->ant = aux;
        }
        nop = no->prox;

}
```

Já criei a estrutura para inserir os elementos em uma Pilha, agora quero passar essa pilha por referência e inserir os elementos da pilha em uma lista duplamente encadeada, mas da forma que estou fazendo ele não tá inserindo os elementos da pilha na lista, nesse código só coloquei pra adicionar o peso.

Comment: Existe algum `typedef` de `Pilha` que não está na pergunta ? Pois ela está a ser utilizada como tipo em `void insere_lista(Lista* l, Pilha *pi){`. O mesmo pergunto em relação ao tipo `Lista`

Answer (score 1):

Corrigido:

```
struct noPilha{
    float peso;
    int idMala;
    char cor[20];
    struct pessoa donoMala;

};

typedef struct noPilha Elem;

struct noLista{
    struct noPilha mala;
    struct noLista *ant;
    struct noLista *prox;
}*aux=0;


typedef struct noLista NoLista;


int cont=0;

void insere_lista(Elem mala){


    NoLista* no = (NoLista*)malloc(sizeof(NoLista));

    if(cont == 0)
    {
        no->prox=0;
        no->ant=0;
        no->mala = mala;
        aux =  no;

    }
    else{
        aux->prox = no;
        no->prox=0;
        no->ant=aux;
        no->mala = mala;

    }
    cont++;
}

void exibe(){

    NoLista * no = aux;
    for(int i =0; i<cont; i++)
    {
        if(no == 0) { continue; }
        printf("id %d", no->mala.peso);
        no = no->prox;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Elem mala1;
    mala1.peso = 1.0f;
    insere_lista(mala1);
    mala1.peso = 2.0f;
    insere_lista(mala1);

    exibe();

    return 0;
}
```

Na sua função de inserção, o seu erro foi nao ter declarado nenhuma referencia,
a variavel aux sempre tem que esta fora da função( no escopo global).

Comment: Onde entra a pilha na sua resposta ? Relembro que o titulo da pergunta diz unir Pilha com Lista, e a função `insere_lista` no código do autor da pergunta, recebe uma lista e uma pilha.

Comment: preste atenção no codigo, 
typedef struct noPilha Elem; logo pilha = Elem                                                a variavel aux é um ponteiro  da struct noLista, e se olhar no codigo do autor da pergunta vera isso:  NoLista* aux = *l; logo Lista * e NoLista* são iguais, portanto a variavel que ele passa como argumento chamada *l é igual a variavel *aux na minha resposta.

Comment: Continuo a não conseguir ver uma união de uma `Pilha` com uma `Lista`, isto é assumindo que uma pilha é uma `Pilha` baseado em LIFO por exemplo e com vários elementos. Uma prova desta minha observação é o fato de ter removido o `struct noPilha* prox;` da sua `struct noPilha`(e que só por sí também não constitui uma estrutura Pilha válida/comum). Pessoalmente acho que a pergunta está simplesmente demasiado incompleta para ser respondida de forma útil à comunidade.